# Show jquery dialog confirm/cancel modal. Form submit on confirm click

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, events, dialog

I have a jquery-ui modal dialog on my page which I show when a user clicks a `Decline` button on a control which is contained within an asp.net `UpdatePanel`, there are many of these controls on the page.

Script:

```
function confirmDecline(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $('form').submit();
                    return true;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Pod markup:

```
<div class="dms-pod">
<ul>
    <li><strong><asp:Literal ID="litCompanyName" runat="server" /></strong></li>
    <li><asp:Literal ID="litVatNumber" runat="server" /></li>
    <li><asp:Literal ID="litTown" runat="server" /></li>
</ul>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDmsForm" runat="server" CssClass="dms-form" DefaultButton="btnAccept">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDmsNumber" runat="server" placeholder="DMS number" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqDmsNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid DMS number" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtDmsNumber" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="valDmsNumber" runat="server" TargetControlID="reqDmsNumber" HighlightCssClass="error" />
    <div class="dms-buttons">
        <div class="container">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAccept" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="accept" OnClick="btnAccept_Click" />
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDecline" runat="server" CssClass="btn-alt" Text="decline" OnClick="btnDecline_Click" OnClientClick="confirmDecline(event)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</asp:Panel>
<div class="clear"></div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDealershipIRLinkID" runat="server" />
```

Which is then contained inside an update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPendingDms" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptPendingDmsRequests" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPendingDmsRequests_ItemDataBound" OnItemCreated="rptPendingDmsRequests_ItemCreated">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <uc:DmsRegisterPod runat="server" ID="ucDmsRegisterPod" />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm using `event.preventDefault()` to stop the button action from firing, however, I'd also like to allow the action to continue if the user clicks the `Confirm` button. I had assumed I could just use:

```
$('form').submit();
```

In the dialog `Confirm` function, but this fires the validators of the other controls in the repeater/update panel. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this, posting the answer in case it helps anyone else facing a similar problem.

I pass in the id of the control which triggered the click:

```
OnClientClick="confirmDecline(event, this.id)"
```

I then fire off `__doPostBack` with this id in the dialog `Confirm` function:

```
function confirmDecline(event, controlId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    controlId = controlId.replace(/_/g, '$');
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                __doPostBack(controlId, '');
                return true;
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
     });
}
```